Regex: Match string with OR withour string delimiter
I'm extracting from bibtex and have a little problem, as the format can have values wrapped inside curly brackets OR NOT.
Please find the example text below:
@article{Roxas_2011, title={Social Desirability Bias in Survey Research on Sustainable Development in Small Firms: an Exploratory Analysis of Survey Mode Effect}, volume={21}, ISSN={1099-0836}, url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/bse.730}, DOI={10.1002/bse.730}, number={4}, journal={Business Strategy and the Environment}, publisher={Wiley}, author={Roxas, Banjo and Lindsay, Val}, year={2011}, month=sep, pages={223\xe2\x80\x93235} }

A you can see, all except month are x={y}, so a simple (PHP preg_match with mUg flags):
[\s,]+(.*)={(.*[^}])}

Does the trick for everything except month=sep.
If I try using ", " as delimited, it aparantly also splits authors.
Can you please help me? :)
Thanks :)

"PHP preg_match with mUg flags": arghhh!!!! U is a syntactic sugar totally useless most of the time, and the g flag doesn't exist in PHP since there are two different functions:  preg_match (that looks for the first match) and preg_match_all (that looks for all matches). The m flag is useless too here since it only changes the behavior of the ^ and $ anchors that aren't in your pattern.

You can use
[\s,]+(.*?)=(?|{([^{}]*)}|(\w+))

Note you should not use any flags with the regex (you may use an s flag to make . match line break chars and you may use u flag to make \w and \s match all Unicode word/whitespace chars - if you need).
See the regex demo.
Details

[\s,]+ - one or more whitespaces or/and commas
(.*?) - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
= - a = char
(?|{([^{}]*)}|(\w+)) - a branch reset group matching:

{([^{}]*)} - a { char, any zero or more chars other than { and } captured into Group 2, a } char.
| - or
(\w+) - Group 2: one or more word chars.




Hi, this worked perfectly for some time (until a platform upgrade, I suppose?) and still works perfectly well on Regex101. Opposed as before and regex101, preg_match_all now captures the match from the beginning until the end of title instead of just title: Array\n(\n    [0] => Array\n        (\n            [0] =>  @article{Roxas_2011, title={Social Desirability Bias in Survey Research on Sustainable Development in Small Firms: an Exploratory Analysis of Survey Mode Effect}\n            [1].... Any ideas how to make it work as on regex101 - aside from cutting until the first {? Thanks!

@May11 So, you mean to say it now matches from the leftmost delimiter to the rightmost one, as if .*? turned into .*? Did anyone turn on the U flag? If yes, do not use this flag, remove it.
